# Delete files with certain prefix using Ansible

Tags: ansible, path, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to delete all files which have the prefix `git` from the directory `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/bin/`. But ansible don't seem to delete the files.

I tried using `file` module:

```
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: 
    - '/usr/local/bin/git*'
    - '/usr/bin/git*'
```

but it's not working.

Comment: file's `path:` doesn't do globbing. Use `find` with `pattern` to gather the items and then delete them ...